# Me too or mine too

Tags: pronouns

> My favorite movie is Star Wars.

If my favorite movie is also Star Wars what should be the response to this, *me too* or *mine too*, or something else?

I found [this](https://www.englishforums.com/English/MeTooMineToo/bjglqv/post.htm) but the answer didn't have any explanation so I wanted to ask it here.

Comment: You can be saying that you are the same as them (me too)  or that your favorite movie is also Star Wars (Mine too)   They both amount to the same thing.

Comment: You can also say, "Same here."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should answer by "mine too".

Whenever the statement you're agreeing with is a possessive one "my favorite ..." or "my dog always ..." you should use "mine too".

"Me too" is an informal (some grammar fanatics would label it ungrammatical) version of "I too". These are used for agreeing with statements that aren't possessive and say something about the person saying them: Person A: *"I received a nonsensical text from John last night."* Person B: *"Me/I too!"* (meaning: "I too received ...")

Hope you find this helpful.